# how to plot bar chart by allowing the user to choose the columns using plotly and python with streamlit

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, streamlit

I have a dataframe consist of 3 columns
I want is to plot the result based on the user selection of the columns.

I am able until now to plot  **bar chart** but with specifying in the code the column and not based on the user input.

If i try the user input the system crash and display the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df =pd.DataFrame({"source_number":[11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,1235],
    "location":["loc1","loc2","loc3","loc1","loc1","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
    "category":["cat1","cat3","cat1","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat1"],
    })

columns = df.columns.tolist()
selected_columns = st.multiselect("select column",columns)
s = df[selected_columns].str.strip().value_counts()

trace = go.Bar(x=s.index,y=s.values,showlegend = True)
layout = go.Layout(title = "test")
data = [trace]
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```py
selected_columns = st.multiselect("select column", columns, default="location")
s = df[selected_columns[0]].str.strip().value_counts()
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: what about if i want to plot a groupby result for multiple columns ?

Comment: @user5980666 And what to do with the `source_number` values? Or do you just want to have `location` and `category`?

Comment: just want to plot location and category result